# Re-Download Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I finally got rid of errors 13 and 1 but now I am dealing with the worst error of all, can not find jvm.dll. So I checked my copy of the JDK and it has two jvm.dll's, server, and client. I also got the 64 bit version of the JDK and Eclipse. I add the JDK to my PATH variable, and put the -vm tag in every directory of the JDK in Eclipse.ini, but still Failed to load shared library jvm.dll.

This is what I have in Ecilpse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product

org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.pl

atform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-vm 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\bin
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not having enough reputation to comment, so first of all, are you sure that have JRE and JDK are correctly installed on your machine these seem to be problems with either the installation of the JDK and JRE or of eclipse itself, also since the problem is with finding a `.dll` file I assume you are running eclipse on a Windows machine, this shouldn't happen if you installed eclipse, the jdk and jre correctly, it should detect all these files automatically, I suggest you to make sure that you installed the correct versions of the JDK and JRE(×86 for 32 bit and ×64 for 64 bit) and reinstalling eclipse again.
P.S: I suggest that you also use the latest version of eclipse, there is an installer now so it should solve most of these problems (or if you used the installer then it may be the cause of the problem and you should install it in the old way (extracting a zip file and creating a shortcut from the eclipse.exe file)) hope this information helps

Comment: Thanks. And I unzipped eclipse from a zip file with Windows Exraction Wizard so that must be the problem. By the way, can you please tell me how to uninstall eclipse properly?

Comment: The old version or the installer? The installer should come with an uninstaller (try running the installer again or try to search the computer for an uninstaller), or of not you can go on windows to control panel > uninstall a program or software, find eclipse and remove it. As for the zip file, just delete the folder and the shortcut (just remember to save the workspace so you won't lose any projects you've worked on)